# Can't create SparkSession in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to run Spark on Spring, the project itself runs without errors, but after I try to create a session, i get this error.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'scala.collection.SeqOps scala.collection.mutable.Buffer$.empty()'
```

pom.xml

```
    <dependencies>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.thoughtworks.paranamer</groupId>
                <artifactId>paranamer</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
            </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>

            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.13</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.15</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

controller

```
@RestController
public class MainController {
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                .builder()
                .appName("AppSpark")
                .config("spark.master", "local")
                .getOrCreate();

        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

I tried to downgrade the versions in the pom file, but it did not help, only the error type changed.

If anyone has come across the same error, I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Scala libraries are compiled against a Scala version which is visible in the artifact name like `spark-sql_2.13` means it's `spark-sql` compiled for Scala 2.13.

You cannot have multiple Scala versions in the same project.

In your case, you have:

- `scala-library`: 2.12
- `spark-core`: 2.12
- `spark.sql`: 2.13

Choose a single version and stick to it. 2.13 if possible as it's more recent.